# How to change material-ui Textfield label styles in react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to Material-UI, I couldn't able to figure it out, how to change the color of the label which is showing in grey color. I want it in `black`. Can anyone help me with this query?

Here is the Code :

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { TextField, Button, Grid } from "@material-ui/core";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Grid container justify={"center"} alignItems={"center"} spacing={1}>
        <Grid item>
          <TextField
            id="outlined-name"
            label="Name"
            value={"Enter value"}
            onChange={() => console.log("I was changed")}
            margin="normal"
            variant="outlined"
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
            Submit
          </Button>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the code: "https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-morning-30owz"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you use the selection tools in your browser, you would find out that:

The class name used is **MuiFormLabel-root**

```
<label class="MuiFormLabel-root MuiInputLabel-root MuiInputLabel-formControl MuiInputLabel-animated MuiInputLabel-shrink MuiInputLabel-outlined MuiFormLabel-filled" data-shrink="true" for="outlined-name">Name</label>
```

So set the styles using [nesting selector](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#nesting-selectors) to the `TextField` component

#### Functional component

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    "& .MuiFormLabel-root": {
      color: "red" // or black
    }
  }
}));
...
const classes = useStyles();
```

#### Classical component

```
import { withStyles, createStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
const styles = theme => createStyles({
  root: {
    "& .MuiFormLabel-root": {
      color: "red"
    }
  }
});
...
const { classes } = this.props;
...
export default withStyles(styles)(App);
```

usage

```
<TextField
  className={classes.root}
  ...
>
</TextField>
```

By this way, you can change the label color, as the screenshot is shown below (currently red)

---

[image]

---

Try it online:

[image: Edit staging-framework-3h4m8]

Comment: Cant we give directly to class Component without creating a functional component?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to leave your style in a separate file, you can write:

```
.MuiTextField-root > label {
    background-color: $bg-color;
    color: $color;
}

.MuiTextField-root > .MuiFormLabel-root.Mui-focused {
    color: $color;
}
```