# Changing the styling in MUI Table

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm creating a Material UI table what I believe is the default way, and I'm getting huge padding internally.

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

I have tried using `withStyles` and passing the resulting class into through the `component` property, like this:

```
const StyledPaper = withStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    padding: "0",
  },
}), Paper);
...
        <Table component={StyledPaper}>
```

I have tried making classes and passing them in:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    padding: "0",
  },
}));
...
    const classes = useStyles();
...
        <Table classes={classes}>
```

I have futzed around endlessly and I'm not having any effect at all.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the DOM element class name, you would find out that it starts with `MuiPaper-root` under the `MuiGrid-root` element.

Perhaps use [nesting selector](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#nesting-selectors) is a good approach in this situation for customized styles

```
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
const styles = {
  root: {
    "& .MuiPaper-root": {
      padding: 0
    }
  }
};
...
const { classes } = this.props;
...
export default withStyles(styles)(App);
```

usage

Notice it's not inside the `Table` so you may want to add the `padding` for `Grid`

```
<Grid container>
  <Grid item className={classes.root} // ...>
    // ...
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

---

Similar online demo and related QA:

[How to change material-ui Textfield label styles in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60736015/how-to-change-material-ui-textfield-label-styles-in-react/60736142#60736142)

[image: Edit staging-framework-3h4m8]

Comment: The nut 'graph of your answer was "Notice it's not inside the Table".  It wasn't.  I assumed that the "panel" was part of the table (owing to a subtle, but total error on my part).  In fact, it was part of the enclosing Component, and I had a line in the JSS reading `panel: { margin: "20%" }`.  When I deleted that, everything looked good.  I'm going to accept your answer because it's so detailed, and you deserve the points.