# Overriding the material-UI style not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am new to the material UI. Here, I am trying to override the CSS of material UI `tabs component.`

```
<Tab
    key={`${tab}_${index}`}
    classes={{
    flexcontainer: css.tabFlexContainer
    }}
    disableRipple
    label={tab.label}
    value={tab.value}
    icon={
    tab.icon ? <Icons className={css.tabIcons} iconname={tab.icon} /> : null
    }
/>
```

So, here I am trying to override the `flexContainer` class with this CSS:

```
. tabFlexContainer {
   width : 100%
  justify -content :space-between
}
```

So, when I am using I am getting a compiled time error only,

> TS2769: No overload matches this call.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Is this `. tabFlexContainer` a typo? If not, you should not have whitespaces between class name and the dot `.`. It should be `.tabFlexContainer`

Comment: it is a typo . But it does not work

Comment: @keikai  any solution will work be okay with me,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, if you check the DOM structure

```html
<div class="MuiTabs-root Tabs" aria-label="disabled tabs example">
  <div class="MuiTabs-scroller MuiTabs-fixed" style="overflow: hidden;">
    <div class="MuiTabs-flexContainer" role="tablist">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>;
```

You would find out that the demand className is **MuiTabs-flexContainer** (rather than `tabFlexContainer`)

Example: For **Tabs**, all the className can be found in the [MUI Tabs CSS API](https://material-ui.com/api/tabs/#css)

---

There are many solutions, except normal `withStyles` and `makeStyles`, for fully override:

#### 1.Material-UI solution

1.1 Use MUI internal style HOC **withStyles** to fully override the component.

Using [nesting selector](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#nesting-selectors)

```
import { Tabs, Tab, withStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

const StyledTabs = withStyles({
  root: {
    background: "light-blue",
    ...
    boxShadow: "0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)",
    "& div.MuiTabs-scroller": {
      "& .MuiTabs-flexContainer": {
        background: "linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)"
      }
    }
  }
})(Tabs);
```

[image]

---

1.2 Use normal **createStyles** or **makeStyles** style solution

Classical component
withStyles (High order function) + createStyles

Functional component
useStyles (hooks) + makeStyles

Refer in details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60736142/11872246

---

#### 2.Styled-Components solution

If you want to use separate CSS files to style MUI component

You can try [styled-components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components)

> styled-components allows you to write actual CSS code to style your components.

Usage:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Tabs, Tab, withStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

const StyledTabs = styled.Tabs`
  font-size: 1.5em;
  ...
`;
```

---

#### 3.Separate Pure CSS solution

Refer: [css_selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

```
import "./styles.css";
```

```css
div.MuiTabs-flexContainer {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, red 30%, #ff8e53 90%);
}
```

[image]

[image: Edit gallant-keller-kwtvj]

Comment: I really appreciate your work ,  but will it possible if we do it the way I mean I have a seperate CSS file and there

Comment: thing is this the way I am following from the start so , could u please help a bit . I  got stuck over here.  :-)

Comment: Sorry But I am not using the styled component for this

Comment: Actually, I am trying to use the classes  props through which I can override the default css property.

Comment: awsome solution man. thank for your efforts . I do have one issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60931950/material-ui-tabs-not-able-to-add-the-text-overflow-elipses-to-the-span-tag.  could u please look at it,

Answer (score 5):

You can use the api(props) provided to `tabs` by [Material-UI here](https://material-ui.com/api/tabs/). like this:

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    tabRoot: {
       // ...
    },
    flexContainer: {
        width : 100%
        justifyContent :"space-between"
    }

}));

export default useStyles;
```

Use in your component:

```
const classes = useStyles();
// ...

<Tabs
    classes={{ flexContainer: classes.flexContainer }} // override for tabs
   ...
>
    <Tab classes={{ root: classes.tabRoot}}  /> // override for tab
</Tabs>
```

See **CSS** section of these links.([Tab](https://material-ui.com/api/tab/), [Tabs](https://material-ui.com/api/tabs/))

Or you can use `className` prop to add css class and override the styles.

Note: It's css in js, then style must be an object(camelCase property) not like css.

Comment: For me, this solution was easiest to implement.

And if you want to override another prop
```js
...
classes={{ flexContainer: classes.flexContainer , indicator:classes.newIndicatorClass}}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard to override Material UI using CSS but you can use either `Styled-Components` or `makeStyle` Hook.

Comment: You forget a `s` for `makeStyles`

Answer (score 1):

you can add  `variant="fullWidth"` to achieve the space-between effect