# Material UI tabs , Not able to add the text-overflow elipses to the span tag

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am new to the material UI. here, I have two tabs and that tabs has some content.

Now, I am trying to add the `text overflow elipses` to this . But the text is in span over there,

```
<Tab
              key={`${tab}_${index}`}
              classes={{
                root: css.tabRoot,
                selected: css.tabSelected,
                wrapper: css.tabIconWrapper,
                labelIcon: css.tabLabelIcon
              }}
              disableRipple
              label={tab.label}
              value={tab.value}
              icon={
                tab.icon ? <Icons className={css.tabIcons} iconname={tab.icon} /> : null
              }
            />
```

Now, Here the label is having a bit more length . So, I am just trying to limit it as `max-width : 100px;`

But in the material UI it is getting a bit complicated to override .

SO, what I tried is ,

```
 label={<Typography className={selectedTab ? '' : ''}>{tab.label}</Typography>}
```

But here

I am not able to get which tab has been selected , I mean I want to add that class if the tab is selected.

can any one help me with this ? any solution like with or without typography works for me.

thanks.

```
  div class="MuiTabs-scroller MuiTabs-fixed" role="tablist" style="overflow: hidden;">
   <div class="MuiTabs-flexContainer">
     <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiTab-root VIP_tabRoot MuiTab-textColorInherit Mui-selected VIP_tabSelected" tabindex="0" type="button" role="tab" aria-selected="true">
       <span class="MuiTab-wrapper VIP_tabIconWrapper">Test004</span>
    </button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @keikai it is like it , I will add all the code which I get in the debugger.

Comment: I have adde some code. I hope it will help to understand my problem.

Comment: Actually I am trying to add some elipses to the span element but they are not getting applied.

Comment: @ganeshkaspate Please create a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) that reproduces your problem.

Comment: @keikai I have updated the code as well. Could you please check this one.