# How to use override Button using Box component in Material-UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've been trying to understand and write code on the Box component in material-UI. (https://material-ui.com/components/box/#box)

I've been trying to override a Button component the two ways it describes in the documentation, but I have no idea how. When I run the code segment using both methods, the button appears but no color change. Then when I try to add an extra Button underneath the clone element code segment I get an error saying 'Cannot read property 'className' of undefined'.

```
            <Box color="primary" clone>
                <Button>Click</Button>
                <Button>Click</Button>
            </Box>
```

When I add a Button component underneath in the second render props way, the first button just disappears from the DOM completely.

```
             <Box color="secondary">
                {props => <Button {...props} > Click </Button>}
                <Button color="secondary">Click</Button>
            </Box>
```

Would appreciate an explanation of how overriding underlying DOM elements work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60926017/11872246

Comment: Unfortunately not. I do want to override styling, but only using either of the methods mentioned within the Box component documentation. Using clone element or render props.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few issues with the code you've shown in your question.

1. `primary` and `secondary` are not valid colors within the palette. They are valid options for the `color` prop of `Button`, but here you are trying to reference colors within the theme's `palette` object. For this purpose, you need `primary.main` and `secondary.main` (which is what [Button uses](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.8/packages/material-ui/src/Button/Button.js#L49) when you specify `<Button color="primary">`).
2. Box only supports a single child when using the `clone` property and it only supports a single child when using the render props approach. In both of your examples you have two children.

---

Here is the [Material-UI source code](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.8/packages/material-ui-styles/src/styled/styled.js#L92) that deals with the clone option:

```
      if (clone) {
        return React.cloneElement(children, {
          className: clsx(children.props.className, className),
          ...spread,
        });
      }
```

This is creating a new child element that combines the `className` generated by `Box` with any existing class name on the child. It gets at this existing class name via `children.props.className`, but when there are multiple children then `children` will be an array of elements and will not have a `props` property so you get the error:

> Cannot read property 'className' of undefined

---

Here is the [Material-UI source code](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.8/packages/material-ui-styles/src/styled/styled.js#L98) that deals with the render props approach:

```
      if (typeof children === 'function') {
        return children({ className, ...spread });
      }
```

When you have more than one child, then `typeof children === 'function'` will not be true and it won't use the render props approach. In this case, both children just get normal react rendering and trying to render a function doesn't render anything.

---

Below is a working example that fixes all of these problems by using a single `Button` child in the `clone` case and a single function child in the render props case (a function that then renders two `Button` elements).

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Box color="primary.main" clone>
        <Button>Click</Button>
      </Box>
      <Box color="secondary.main">
        {props => (
          <>
            <Button {...props}> Click </Button>
            <Button color="secondary">Click</Button>
          </>
        )}
      </Box>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Box clone and render props]

Comment: Amazing explanation! Thanks so much.

Comment: So I just changed my code to match yours in my React project and the color of the buttons are still not changing. I took a screenshot. https://imgur.com/a/4EY6upk

Comment: The order of the imports matters. You have Box before Button, but I have it after. The order of import impacts the order of the resulting styles in the `<head>` and therefore which styles win when specificity is the same. Unfortunately, the order that matters is the order in which they are **first** imported, so even an import of `Box` in some other page that is used before `Button` is ever imported has the potential to mess this up.

Comment: You can find more explanation of this import order effect in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56929702/material-ui-v4-makestyles-exported-from-a-single-file-doesnt-retain-the-styles/56941531#56941531

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks so much.