# How to override Box created by TabPanel in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, material-ui

I'm struggling to target the Mui Box that seems to be automatically generated by the Material UI TabPanel.  (It would be even better if I could turn it off and use my own container div).

It's giving me a default padding of 24px that i need to override.

There is no documentation on the TabPanel as far as I can see on the website.

[image]

I am guessing I would need to put classes={{}} on the TabPanel in my react code but can't seem to get it to work.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Could you provide some of your code? It's hard to tell without any code. And MUI doesn't have something so-called `TabPanel`, there are only `Tab` and `Tabs`.

Comment: One more thing, since the `Box` is not exposed by `Tab` API, you can use nesting sector to select this class to give styles, but the code is needed at the first place

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60926017/11872246

Comment: Thanks @keikai - Yes that has sorted it out!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer to my direct question that worked for me was to use the following:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    tab: { 
        '& .MuiBox-root': {
          padding: '0px',
          },
        },
    }));
```

I then added this to the TabPanel

```
<TabPanel value={value} index={0} classes={{ root: classes.tab }}>
```

But as also pointed out - it was actually the TabPanel function from the Material UI pages Tab demo that was creating the Box - so it was possible to remove it anyway!

Comment: Yeah, I changed the Box attribute `p` aka `padding` to zero

Comment: <TabPanel value={value} index={0} className={ classes.tab }>