# Material-UI issue with makeStyles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have faced the following issue:

```
 ...
 var useStyles = makeStyles(function (theme) {
  11 |     var _a;
> 12 |     return createStyles({
  13 |         button: {
 ...
```

`package.json` with material-ui deps:

```
...
"@material-ui/core": "4.9.7",
"@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
"@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.45",
"@material-ui/pickers": "3.2.8",
"jss": "^10.0.2",
"material-ui": "^0.20.2",
"mdi-material-ui": "^6.2.0",
...
```

I have no idea what went wrong. Other related answers on StackOverflow didn't helped me. So, I hope you could help me with that issue!
Thanks

Comment: Please show the full code of your component

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `createStyles` with **makeStyles** inside a functional component.

- Classical: withStyles (High order function) + createStyles
- Functional: useStyles (hooks) + makeStyles

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  button: {
  }
}));

const classes = useStyles();
```

---

Refer:

- Material-UI: [styles document](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#stress-test)
- Related QA: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60736142/11872246

Comment: This is not my component, I am only use it and I am not able to make changes to it. 
This component produces following exception.